# Should I worry about IE6 and below?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, social-networking

I've pretty much made my website design compatible across the board, except with IE6 and below. Now I'm sure some would agree that IE 6 has been a problem for a while.

My question is this. It's almost 2012, should I even attempt to satisfy the limitations of IE6?

If my project was in any other genre than what it is, I wouldn't think twice about worrying about it. I noticed other programmers and designers just ignoring it completely when constructing their websites. The thing is, my project is a social networking site, similar to Facebook/Youtube/Twitter.

I'd like to know an estimated number of how many people still use that terrible browser if anyone has a source, and do you think that market would even be interested in social networking?

Comment: That's up to you. I would at least give IE6 basic functionality and a huge, violently-flashing warning.

Comment: there no need to worry about IE6 check these links http://www.byebyeinternetexplorer.org/en,  http://sixrevisions.com/web-development/farewell-ie6/

Comment: This isn't really a programming question.  This is a user requirement.

Comment: Well, it directly effects the way I program my website and how people view it, I see it as an appropriate question. I'm sorry you don't. I trust the opinion of professionals over a gut instinct and I'd rather be safe than sorry.

Comment: Thanks to everyone else for the advice, and the statistics of browser use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the browser stats you can see that ie6 is a very small percentage of browsers. [link](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201011-201111)

I'd personally not support it and redirect or show a splash screen informing the user that their browser is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp) for browser popularity.  The link to "Browser Explorer" at the top left shows you the stats for the different versions of Explorer.  As of October, 2011, IE 6 is at 1.3%.

Unless your web site is specifically targeting corporate users (which it sounds like it isn't) where some companies still force IE 6 to be used, I'd say it's safe to ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

---------------**NO**-------------------